# Hyperledger Fabric GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP & GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINTS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I was looking into the `docker` configuration files and found two parameters in peer environment as shown below:

```
environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
```

Can anyone explain what there two variables **CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP** & **CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT**  works. How they can be configured in case of odd number of peers.

A detailed explanation would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Gossip can be used just between peers in the same organization or between peers in different organizations.  It is always scoped to specific channels.

1) Communication between the peers in a single organization

- One peer may be the leader and connect to the ordering service and deliver blocks to other peers in its own organization
- A peer can connect to other peers in its organization to obtain missing blocks

2) Communication between peers in different organizations

- In v1.2 when using the private data feature, gossip is used to distribute the private data to other peers in the org at endorsement time
- Peers can get missing blocks that have been already committed, from peers in other organizations
- Peers can get missing private data from peers in other organizations at commit time

In order for gossip to actually work, it needs to be able to obtain the endpoint information for peers in its own organization as well as from peers in other organizations.

**CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP** is used to bootstrap gossip within an organization.  If you are using gossip, you will typically configure all the peers in your org to point to an initial set of peers for bootstrap (you can specific a space-separated list of peers).  Off course peers can bootstrap from different peers as well, but in that case you just need to make sure that there's a bootstrap path across all peers.  Peers within an organization will typically communicate on their internal endpoints (meaning you do not have to expose all the peers in an org publicly).  When the peer contacts the bootstrap peer, it passes it's endpoint info and then gossip is used to distribute the info about all the peers in the organization among the peers in the organization.

In order for peers to communicate across organizations, again some type of bootstrap information is required.  The initial cross-organization bootstrap information is provided via the "anchor peers" setting in the channel configuration.  This allows peers who have joined a channel to discover other peers on the channel as well.  But clearly initially a peer in on organization will only know about the anchor peers for there organizations.  If you want to make other peers in your organization known to other organizations, then you need to set the **CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT** property.  If this is not set, then the endpoint information about the peer will not be broadcast to peers in other organizations, and in fact - that peer will only be known to its own organization.

Comment: Thanks Gari for such detailed answer. Do I need to specify just one peer’s address in GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP? Or Can I provide an array of other peer’s address?

Comment: You can actually specific a comma-separate list of bootstrap peers.  Edited my answer above as well

Comment: @GariSingh This is my docker compose base configuration https://hastebin.com/inomihopek.cs but no luck getting error https://hastebin.com/axosecuzuj.rb Any help appreciated . I am running 2 organization with each 3 peers.

Comment: @GariSingh told me it should be comma separated .let me try with space

Comment: In a multi-host network, CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT should have the value of IP: port ?

Comment: It depends.  Could be `host:port` or `IP:port`  ... if you are using TLS, then the certificate for your peer must have a SAN matching the `host` and/or `IP` you specify

Comment: Thanks for this detailed information.

Comment: @GariSingh on kubernetes we have gateways and services for peers, if as a service core peer address is on peer0-org1:7051 and gateway is configured on peer0.org1.com:9051, then what should be the GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT

Note: the org2 is on a different cluster with different gateway, it does not have knowledge of where peer0-org1 is.

Comment: ` peer0.org1.com:9051` should be used as the `GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT ` in this case assuming it is accessible from outside of the cluster.