# What does these properties mean in Fabric docker image?

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

```
- CORE_PEER_ID=shop-peer
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=shop-peer:7051
- CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=shop-peer:7051
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=build-blockchain-insurance-app_default
```

I have these properties in docker.

Question 1) I know what `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT` means, but why in the examples do they specify the same peer. What I mean is, these properties are for shop-peer and in external-endpoint, it specified itself(shop-peer:7051).

Question 2) what is `CORE_PEER_ID` ? is its value related to some other things in Fabric so that if I don't write shop-peer here, shall I have the error or I can specify whatever name I want in `CORE_PEER_ID`?

Question 3) what is `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT` and `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` and what do they mean?

Answer (score 3):

- **CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT** - this is the endpoint used by external peers to communicate with this peer. Can be different to the internal endpoint due to the use of port mapping through firewalls for external connections.
- **CORE_PEER_ID** - this is used by the peer to build the name of the chaincode container, so it at least needs to be unique for all peers running on a single machine. It's likely also used elsewhere as a unique identifier, so should be unique, but can be any value.
- **CORE_VM_ENDPOINT** - used by the peer to create/run docker containers for running chaincode.
- **CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE** - sets the network used by chaincode containers.

Comment: the 2nd part of this answer also might contain some further relevant info https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379353/573034