# HL Fabric Gossip bootstrap and endpoint for orgs with single peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

This is helpful but not current for HLF 1.4.3. 
[Hyperledger Fabric GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP & GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377474/hyperledger-fabric-gossip-bootstrap-gossip-externalendpoints)

@GariSingh, @yacovm would you know, if our config consists of 5 orgs, each with a single peer, each with a single CA and one network orderer, would the following be correct for docker-compose-base.yaml?

IOW, is the following correct for GOSSIP for two of the example peers:

```
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:8051

CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.orgA.example.com:13051
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.orgA.example.com:14051
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@CT99, it's fine, assuming orgA is a second organization

You can have a single peer per organization but it is advisable to have two peers per organization,

**reg gossip**:

If you use private data concept then it is must else it's optional